# How to disable a rollback when the deployment fails with XLDeploy

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-cli, jenkins-groovy, xl-deploy, deployit

I'm searching on how to disable the rollback process when my deployment is broken ( is on error) with XLDeploy ( using the plugin within jenkinsFile).

the following possible strategies for deployment failures. The XL Deploy task can

Rollback the deployment 
Cancel the deployment 
Leave the deployment as-is ( I'm looking for this option without roll back) 
Is there a flag to pass to the XLDeploy ( or any approch ) to make sure that there is no need to perform a rollback when the deployment is failing?

## here is my jenkins file pipeline

```
stage('Deploy') { 
xldDeploy serverCredentials: 'xld-admin', environmentId: 'Environments/env', packageId: 'Applications/app_new/1.0'

// where to put this option to cancel the rollback 
}
```

When i look to the source code I found this one on https://github.com/jenkinsci/xldeploy-plugin/blob/f11cdceb0ecb1ede28386c40a6303520f7225abe/src/main/java/com/xebialabs/deployit/ci/server/DeployCommand.java
/// snippet

```
} catch (RuntimeException e) { 
try { 
if (deploymentOptions.rollbackOnError) { 
// perform a rollback 
listener.error("Deployment failed, performing a rollback"); 
executeTask(deploymentService.rollback(taskId)); 
} 
} finally { 
throw new DeployitPluginException(e.getMessage()); 
}
```

i.e as i undrestand there is this flag that control the rollback ( active or not) haw to use it on my JnekinsFile

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently these are available parameters for Deploying a package to a environment using jenkinsFile Pipeline Which doesnot have "Rollback On Error",

**xldDeploy**: Step to deploy artifacts on environments in the XL Deploy server using Jenkins, Parameters:-

> serverCredentials                  Type: String
>
> packageId                          Type: String
>
> environmentId                      Type: String       ID of the
>   environment in XL Deploy to which the artifact should be deployed.
>   Jenkins environment variables can be used to specify this value. For
>   example: Environments/Dev
>
> overrideCredentialId (optional)   Type: String

This parameter is available through Jenkins UI only .. see below screenshot,

[image]

Comment: tankyou In fact, I got the response from the support Xbea Chanel. and They tell me that there is no way to do it within the Jenkins file at this moment. It will be considered as a new future perhaps